# json_encode of array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I have the following array of arrays:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "abc"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "įāē"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "čaē"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "qwe"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the bellow code to echo the result on a page:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

I get the following result on my page:

```
[[["abc",null],[null,"qwe"]]]
```

Every string with special char is converted to null.
So I´ve tried `utf8_encode` on each of the element in the array:

```
foreach($array as &$subarray1){
    foreach($subarray1 as &$subarray2){
        foreach($subarray2 as &$subarray3){
            $subarray3 = utf8_encode($subarray3);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following result:

```
[[["abc","\u00e1\u00e2\u00e7"],["\u00e8a\u00e7","qwe"]]]
```

What is the proper way to encode this?

Comment: *"\u00e1"* means *"į"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) supports a second parameter so you can use the constant [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode) like the following:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [0 => "abc", 1 => "įāē"],
    1 => [0 => "čaē", 1 => "qwe"]
];

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

> **You can find a working demo here:** https://ideone.com/J5bvT5